# VS Code - Python Local function references

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have one question related to using the Local / Globa / Python Functions in other function. To give you overview . I have multiple files and those files are connected by calling the Local Function inside. I handover several variables and also the libraries / modules like "pandas", "numpy", others. What is interesting and unfortunately not working in VS Code is references for those handover variables, where i miss VS Code shorcut for "F12" ... also lighter is not forking. Don you know how to correct it?

**Examples:**

**Import in local function (pandas):**
[image: Import in local function (pandas)]

--> you can see that color of "DataFrame" is green so lighter recognize is and can work as with module

**Import in main function (pandas):**
[image: Import in main function (pandas)]

--> here when "pandas" was loaded in main.py and handovere to "Function.py" then inside Local function the color is blue (as variables) and I totally miss module lighting and whisperer

Is there a way how to enable it?

Reason why I want to handover it to local is that I will import it only once and use it in multiple Local functions.

PS: Summary formula in Local function is for nothing here (just to have something to return)

Comment: how should `Funtion.py` know it is called from `main.py` and that the argument is a module. Don't pass modules to functions, just import the module in the other file. In `sum` `pandas` is **JUST** an argument and thus blue in this theme